# PHP show listbox FirstName and LastName

Tags: php, sql-server

I am a new web developer by using PHP and MS SQL

I have already created my database on MS SQL as id, FirstName, LastName, etc.

I write a PHP to connect to my database with listbox (drop down) so I want to show FirstName

and LastName in my listbox but now I can show only FirstName

This is my code...

[image]

May anyone help me.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only printing out the first name in the select box. Maybe try something similar to this.

```
while($name = $firstnameresult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<option value="" . $name['FirstName'] . "">" . $name['FirstName'] . " " . $name['LastName'] . "</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if ur query result contains lastname too then u can use this

```
 echo '<option value="'.$name["Firstname"].'" >'.$name["Firstname"].' '.$name["Lastname"].'</option>';
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you want this..try this code

```
echo '<select id="" name="" ">
   <option value="'.$row["First_name"].'">'.$row["First_name"].' '.$row["Last_name"].'</option>
     </select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo '<option value="' . $name['FirstName'] . '">' . implode(' ', array($name['Firstname'], $name['LastName'])) . '</option>\n';
```